# Prove $\{a\} = \{b,c\} \text{ iff } a=b=c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

> Prove $\{a\}=\{b,c\} \iff a=b=c$

When I try to demonstrate this I only get as far as $a=b \lor a=c \space$ and I can´t yet get to the $a=b \land a=c \space$ or  $a=b \land b=c \space$ part of the demonstration

Comment: $b\in\{a\}$ and $c\in\{a\}$, so...?

Comment: What?  What's to prove?  $a$ is the only element in $\{a\}$, $b$ and $c$ are in $\{b,c\}$.  So if $\{a\} = \{b,c\}$ then $a,b,c$ are all the only element in $\{a\}$.  And if $a=b=c$ then $\{b,c\} =\{a,a\} = \{a\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $\{a\}=\{b,c\}$. Then $\{b,c\}\subseteq\{a\}\implies b,c\in\{a\}$, so we must have $b=a$ and $c=a$ since $\{a\}$ has one element: $a$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $a=b=c$. Then $\{a\}=\{a,a\}=\{b,c\}$. More explicitly, take $x\in\{a\}$, then $x=a=b$ since $a=b$, so $x\in\{b,c\}\implies \{a\}\subseteq\{b,c\}$. Now take $x\in\{b,c\}$, then $x=b$ or $x=c$, but in either case $x=a$ since $a=b=c$, so $x\in\{a\}\implies \{b,c\}\subseteq\{a\}$. Hence, $\{a\}=\{b,c\}$.

Comment: This feels impossibly pedantic, but could you elaborate rigorously on why  $b,c \in \{a\}$ implies $b=a$ and $c=a$? You have justified it by saying (in words, not logic) that it is because $\{a\}$ has one element: $a$. but this seems to rely on some notion of cardinality which shouldn't be necessary for this proof.

Comment: I guess I realized an answer to my own question. I think the point is to realize that notation like $b \in \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ is shorthand for $b = a_1 \lor b= a_2 \lor \ldots \lor b = a_n$. In that case we have directly that $b \in \{a\} \implies b=a$.

Comment: @Jagerber48 saying $b\in A$ means that $b$ is equal to exactly one of the elements in $A$ for any set $A$ (even infinite ones). So if $A=\{a\}$ then $b$ has to be $a$ because there are no other elements for it to be.

Answer (score 0):

By the axiom of extensionality, if $\{b,c\}=\{a\}$, then $x \in \{b,c\}$ if and only if $x\in \{a\}$. So if $x$ is either $b$ or $c$, then $x$ is $a$. I.e. both $b$ and $c$ are identical to $a$.

Answer (score 0):

You said: $a\in\{b,c\} \Rightarrow a=b\lor a=c$.

ALSO: $b\in\{a\}\land c\in\{a\} \Rightarrow b=a\land c=a$